# Writing integration tests to check whether app's routing works correctly

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I'm currently trying to write an integration test which checks the full working of my app.

My biggest problem right now is trying to get the component rendered by my MainTemplate container, to change according to how it changes in a live environment. Basically what I'm trying to do is get the MainTemplate to render HomePage component, which i managed to accomplish and then to change to a different Route after clicking on the Link element in HomePage component. **That should result in rendering DictionaryRooms component.**

The results aren't what I expected them to be, with Jest snapshot still rendering HomePage even after simulating 'click'. Any ideas would be very welcome. Thanks in advance

```
const wrapper = mount(
    <Root>
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']} initialIndex={0}>
            <MainTemplate>
                <Route
                    path="/dictionaries"
                    render={() => (
                        <MainTemplateContent
                            title="Dictionaries"
                        >
                            <Route path="/dictionaries/rooms" component={DictionaryRooms} />
                        </MainTemplateContent>
                    )}
                />
                <Route
                    exact
                    path="/"
                    render={() => (
                        <MainTemplateContent title="">
                            <HomePage />
                        </MainTemplateContent>
                    )}
                />
            </MainTemplate>
        </MemoryRouter>
    </Root>
);



it("renders HomePage", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(HomePage).length).toEqual(1);
});

it("link to dictionaries exists", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find("[href='/dictionaries']").length).toEqual(1);
});

it("clicking on link to dictionaries renders ", () => {
    wrapper
        .find("[href='/dictionaries']")
        .simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```